# Convert various datetime formats to an specific one

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm developing an application where I get various datetime formats from users (like `27/02/2016 12:00:00 AM`,`02/28/16 12:00:00 AM`,`4/18/2016 00:00:00`,...) and I have to convert all to `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss`.

I tried:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateText,"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
DateTime.ParseExact(dateText,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
```

I also replaced `null` by `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which mentioned in [many questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%2027%2F02%2F2016%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM%20-%20String%20was%20not%20recognized%20as%20a%20valid%20DateTime.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=c%23%20String%20was%20not%20recognized%20as%20a%20valid%20DateTime.) about converting string to datetime.

But I always get:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I can convert `27/02/2016 12:00:00 AM` if I code like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateText,"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

But that's not what I want.

Is there anyway to convert any datetime format to `M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` using one line code or at least a method?

Comment: Did you try to use Parse insteadof ParseExact? I think the method names gives you an excelent hint.

Comment: Sure. But how do you deal with `01/02/2016 12:00:00 AM` is that `01 Feb` or `Feb 02`?

Comment: You mean `Jan 02`. @Aron

Answer (score 1):

If you know what all the possible formats are then you should call the overload of `DateTime.TryParseExact` that takes an array of allowable formats.  Otherwise, you should probably call `DateTime.TryParse`, which will test all possible standard formats for the current culture.

If you know for a fact that the text is valid then you can use `ParseExact` or `Parse` instead and then call `ToString` directly on the result.  If you do use one of the `Try` methods then you'll first have to test whether the conversion was successful and, if it is was, then you can call `ToString` on the result.

Comment: Converting `28/02/16 12:00:00 AM` to `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss` is not possible using `Parse` cause my windows datetime setting is `M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` and the given date is `dd/M/yy h:mm:ss tt`. So knowing that TryParse will return `false` for this value, what can I do about it to turn it to what I want?

Comment: Did I not give you two options or did you just not read what I posted?

Comment: Using `Try` just checks if the string is a valid date. which in my case it returns `false` for `28/02/16 12:00:00 AM`. But I'm looking for a way to turn that value into `DateTime`. I don't see such information in your answer

Comment: It's almost as though I never said that you can use `TryParseExact` with multiple formats.

Comment: @AlexJolig jmcilhinney is quite right. I have you have a different formatted strings and you want to parse them to `DateTime`, you **have to** know their formats _exactly_. Other than that, you _might_ have an ambiguous situations as said `01/02/2016` will be `Jan 2nd` or `Feb 1st`. I would suggest you to use `DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` overload. Put your _all_ possible formats as an array in a second parameter.

Comment: @SonerGönül, correct but, unless you know for sure that the input will be one of the valid formats, use `TryParseExact` rather than `ParseExact`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I disagree on that.`TryParse` or `TryParseExact` are great for when strings have come from an _unreliable source_. If we **%100** sure about the format information, using a `TryXXX` method is not a good option at all. `ParseExact` is a better option in this case because you _should_ throw an exception when you have an invalid data about your formats since _you think you sure %100 about their formats_.

Comment: @SonerGönül, in what universe are users reliable sources? Exceptions should be thrown ONLY in exceptional circumstances. A user entering invalid data is NOT exceptional. Validating user input and using it only if it's valid is the very essence of what `Try...` methods exist for. Mind you, it depends exactly what "I get various datetime formats from users" means in the OP. We're not arguing about what these methods are for, but rather what constitutes a reliable source. We may not even disagree on that but rather just be making different assumptions about the OP's words.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think we say really close things. As you said, _Exceptions should be thrown ONLY in exceptional circumstances_. A situation like getting an unexpected format when you %100 sure is an _exceptional_. Now I look at the meaning of _various_ word in Google Translate to be sure about what OP try to say and kind of agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it like this :

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what is `.fff` and where did `datetime` come from?